# Cannot add clickListener for button in Popup

Tags: android

I have popup in my android app. In popup I have button for closing popup with id="imbClosePopUp", but when I try to set to that button clickListener app crashs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#AAAAAAAA">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    >
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imbClosePopUp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/close"
    ></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="CEKIRAJ OBAVEZNE KRITERIJUME"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView> 
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <TableRow>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkw"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="cg"
            ></CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkq"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="tv"
            ></CheckBox>
        </TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveCrit"
            android:text="ok"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set onclicklistener for button imbClosePopUp in function where I create Popup ( I create Popup on click some button ).

```
  private OnClickListener AdditionalC = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            roomate.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          pw = new PopupWindow(
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false), 
            300, 
            300, 
            true);
         // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
         pw.showAtLocation(roomate.findViewById(R.id.tbC), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 

         ImageButton imbClosePopUp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imbClosePopUp);
         imbClosePopUp.setOnClickListener(ClosePopUp);


        }
    };
```

Does anybody know what is the ptoblem and how to colse popup ?

Comment: Well firs of all we need to see your stacktrace. Second, this looks like a really bad implementation of whatever you're doing. Why are you not just using a dialog?

Comment: What is the difference of dialog and popup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question alright, I suspect the problem is here:

```
ImageButton imbClosePopUp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imbClosePopUp);
```

That's `Activity.findViewById()` you're calling there, right? But you presumably want to be searching the *popup*'s layout, not the activity's. Try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
    roomate.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false);
    pw = new PopupWindow(popupView, 300, 300, true);
    pw.showAtLocation(roomate.findViewById(R.id.tbC), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 

    ImageButton imbClosePopUp=(ImageButton)popupView.findViewById(R.id.imbClosePopUp);
    imbClosePopUp.setOnClickListener(ClosePopUp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

imbClosePopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner()
{

```
finish();
```

});